# Python datetime.strptime with Korean locale on Windows

Tags: python, windows, datetime, locale

I have a korean date string that looks like this:

> 월요일, 2019년 08월 05일 09:33:39

and I'm trying to parse it using `datetime.strptime` by setting the locale to `kor` (on Windows). The format is `%A, %Y년 %m월 %d일 %H:%M:%S`.

```py
import locale
from datetime import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'kor')

date_string = '월요일, 2019년 08월 05일 09:33:39'
fromat = '%A, %Y년 %m월 %d일 %H:%M:%S'

time = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)

print(time)
```

This works fine with other languages (e.g. English, German, French) with a slightly different format string - obviously. However, the code above raises a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: time data '월요일, 2019년 08월 05일 09:33:39' does not match format '%A, %Y년 %m월 %d일 %H:%M:%S'
```

I also tried to generate a date string with `datetime.strftime`:

```py
import locale
from datetime import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'kor')

print(datetime.now().strftime('%A'))
# Prints '¿ù¿äÀÏ'
```

Whereas `¿ù¿äÀÏ` does not match the weekday which would be `월요일` (Monday).

I've also tried decoding and encoding with `UTF-8` or `unicode-escape` which all don't really work.

All the above code runs well on Mac/Linux using the `ko_KR` locale. However, `ko_KR` does not work on Windows either.

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on here? Somehow the locale and language support does not properly work with foreign characters.

Comment: `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` before invoking `python` could help.

Comment: Thanks I just tried that. I still get the same result. Any idea on how I can verify whether `python` actually uses `utf-8`?

Comment: Apply `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'kor')` instead of `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME,'kor')`. This works for me in Python 3.5.1 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'kor')` instead of `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'kor')` as follows:

```
d:\bat> python -q
>>>
>>> import locale
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> ### generate a date string with datetime.strftime
...
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'kor')  ### crucial point ###
'Korean_Korea.949'
>>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
('Korean_Korea', '949')
>>> print(datetime.now().strftime('%A')) # Prints 월요일  (right!)
월요일
>>>
>>> ### parsing korean date string
...
>>> date_string = '월요일, 2019년 08월 05일 09:33:39'
>>> fromat = '%A, %Y년 %m월 %d일 %H:%M:%S'
>>>
>>> time = datetime.strptime(date_string, fromat)
>>> print(time)
2019-08-05 09:33:39
>>>
```

FYI, here are some other test cases (*Python 3.5.1 64 bit (AMD64) on win32*):

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

locale.getdefaultlocale()            # Echoes ('cs_CZ', 'cp65001')
locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)     # Echoes (None, None) 
print(datetime.now().strftime('%A')) # Prints Monday            (wrong?)

# user’s default setting for LC_TIME category
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '') # Echoes 'Czech_Czechia.utf8' 
locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)     # Echoes ('Czech_Czechia', 'utf8')
print(datetime.now().strftime('%A')) # Prints pondÄÃ­            (wrong!)

# user’s default setting for all categories
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')  # Echoes 'Czech_Czechia.utf8'
locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)     # Echoes ('Czech_Czechia', 'utf8')
print(datetime.now().strftime('%A')) # Prints pondělí            (right!)

################################################

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'kor')
locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
print(datetime.now().strftime('%A')) # Prints ¿ù¿äÀÏ             (wrong!)

################################################
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a solution would be:

1. rename month to number of month

   ```
   u'january'.replace('january', 1)
   ```
2. select by occurrence of substring per month

   ```
   ddrs={1:u'янв', 2:u'фев' , 3:u'мар' , 4:u'апр' , 5:u'ма' , 6:u'июн' , 7:u'июл',8:u'авг' , 9:u'сент' , 10:u'окт' , 11:u'ноя' , 12:u'дек'}

   numMonth = next((x for x in ddrs if 'январь'.find(ddrs[x])>-1), None)
   ```

The second idea is implemented as a class https://gist.github.com/mrbannyjo/f83b1a2ab302b0afee49d976de365aae

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure, this would work and most likely resolve my issue. However, I am not a fan of hard coded locale strings, especially as I am not familiar with the Korean language. Thus, I decided to use @JosefZ 's answer, as it most likely resembles the most pythonic way to parse a (Korean) date string.